# Soma quantidade de registros por ano e mês

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Preciso gerar um arquivo Json que irá alimentar um gráfico.  Necessito carregar as seguintes informações. Tenho um formulário que recebe data(dd/mm/aaaa).

Meu gráfico exibe a quantidade de visitas cadastradas por ano x mes.

Faço a seguinte conferência no meu  banco:

```
        visitYearGraphic.year = moment(visit.date).format('YYYY');
        visitYearGraphic.month = moment(visit.date).format('MM');
        visitYearGraphics.push(visitYearGraphic);
        var ano13 = 0;
        var ano15 = 0;
        var ano15 = 0;
        _.each(visitYearGraphics, function (visitYearGraphic) {
          if(visitYearGraphic.year=="2015" && visitYearGraphic.month=="01"){
           armazeno qtde de registros
          }

          ... e assim para os demais meses de 2015
        });
```

Porém queria um método com um código limpo para criar esta função. Porque da maneira acima, vai ficar gigante.

Comment: Que formato de objeto esse gráfico espera?

Comment: Podes explicar ou dar exemplo do que queres dizer com "vai ficar gigante"? Ainda nõ percebi que dados queres usar e como.

Comment: [{"_id":"55e5e6440e5a7a3017552acc","qtde":"4","month":"02","year":"2016"}]   Ou seja:    Verifiquei o ano, o mes e a quantidade de registros naquele mes, que foram 4.

Comment: Esse é o retorno do banco, certo ? Você tem que transformar isso em um objeto que o gráfico entenda, certo?

Comment: Sergio, ja esta lá o exemplo, se eu fizer a contagem usando  if(visitYearGraphic.year=="2015" && visitYearGraphic.month=="01"). FIcara enorme. Impossivel de se fazer, no momento meu registro é pequeno, mas daqui 2 anos não será mais!

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, sim, este é o retorno do banco. Porém o fiz usando aquela formula acima, comparando mes e ano. Quero algo diferente disto, porque suponha que eu tenho 6 anos, 12 meses pra cada 6 anos e n registros.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, meu gráfico ja entende este registro. O problema esta na forma que estou usando para receber estes dados que não é a viável. Pois como disse, hj meu registro é pequeno, futuramente nao será mais. Não posso comprar ano a ano e mes a mes de cada ano. Queria uma forma melhor de fazer.

Comment: Mas o que você vai fazer dentro daquela comparação(do if), isso que não ficou muito claro, eu acho.

Comment: Então, estou comparando a quantidade de registros por ano e mês. Ex:  Ano 2015 e mês Janeiro, verifico quantos registros possui e armazeno na variavel qtde.    Porem, faço isso pra cada porque hj tenho poucos registros, mas daqui 2 anos já serão muitos. Quero uma forma melhor de montar o algoritmo, sem ter que fazer assim, um a um.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito você quer uma coleção para contabilizar os acessos, certo?

```
var acessos = {};

_.each(visitYearGraphics, function (visitYearGraphic) {
    var key = visitYearGraphic.year + "." + visitYearGraphic.month;

    if (!acessos.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        acessos[key] = 0;
    }

    acessos[key]+= Number(visitYearGraphic.qtde);
});
```

O código acima irá resultar no seguinte objeto, por ex.:

```
{
    "2015.01": 4,
    "2015.02": 10,
    ...
}
```

Serve assim ? Depois dá pra iterar sobre esse objeto também.

Comment: Serve sim, obrigada. Vou trabalhar em cima disto.

Answer (score 1):

## Pré agregação

Se você já sabe a forma que pretende consultar os dados, aqui tem um caso de uso que deve resolver:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/

No entanto, se você quer consultar de formas diferentes, sugiro agregar na hora da consulta:

## Agregação

Tenho uma situação parecida, e usei a [agregação do próprio MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/), com o [acumulador $sum](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). Veja um exemplo:

Considerando uma coleção "visitas" com os seguintes documentos:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "url" : "http://a", "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "url" : "http://b", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "url" : "http://a", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "url" : "http://a", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "url" : "http://b", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
```

#### Obtendo o total de visitas por dia

```
db.visitas.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {$year: "$date"},
        month: {$month: "$date"},
        day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"}
      },
      total: {$sum: 1}
    }
  }
])
```

O resultado seria:

```
{ "_id": { "year": 2014, "month": 1, "day": 1 }, "total": 1 }
{ "_id": { "year": 2014, "month": 2, "day": 3 }, "total": 2 }
{ "_id": { "year": 2014, "month": 2, "day": 15 }, "total": 2 }
```

#### Obtendo o total de visitas por URL em determinado período

```
db.visitas.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date: {$gt: ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z")}
    },
    $group: {
      _id: "$url",
      total: {$sum: 1}
    }
  }
])
```

O resultado seria:

```
{ "_id": "http://a", "total": 3 }
{ "_id": "http://b", "total": 2 }
```

Veja mais exemplos aqui: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

E outros operadores úteis:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/

No mongoose seria algo assim:

```
Visitas.aggregate()
  .match({date: {$gt: ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z")}})
  .group({_id: "$url", total: {$sum: 1}})
```

Mais sobre agregação no mongoose:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-group